# What is the best translation for "Slice" as in "I ate two slices of cake."

Tags: selección-de-palabras, comida

What is the best way to say "I ate two **slices** of **cake**."?

What should be used for **slice**? Pedazo, trozo, rebanada, parte...

Comment: What possibilities did you come upon? Have you checked any dictionaries?

Comment: Question was edited to make it more suitable for this site, and a better learning material.

Comment: I have removed the second half of your question, asking about the best word for 'cake'--for that I suggest a second question (and be sure to specify which *type* of cake you're referring to--cake is a very broad word in English, referring to anything from a fluffy desert, to mud on ones shoes).

Answer (score 4):

Yo diría:

> Me comí dos rebanadas de pastel.

o tambien

> Comí dos pedazos de pastel.

Comment: Añado *Comí dos porciones de pastel*, *Comí dos tajadas de pastel* o *Comí dos trozos de pastel* (este último es el más común)

Comment: No olvidemos "cachos", burdo y poco elegante, pero muy utilizado.

Comment: Se me olvidó por completo, es completamente normal decir eso.

Comment: En España no he oído nunca hablar de rebanadas, las rebanadas son para el pan, nunca lo he oído referido a un pastel.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "trozos" for a casual talk, or "porciones" for a formal situation.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the shape of the cake. Seriously!

- A "rodaja" is usually round in shape, like a wheel ("rodaja" is related to "rueda").
- A "rebanada" is literally a "slice"; i.e., similar to a "rodaja", but not necessarily round, like a slice of bread.
- A "pedazo" or "trozo" (they're basically synonyms) can be of any shape. It's just a part of something.
- A "porción" is similar to "pedazo" and "trozo", but is usually meant to be a well-shaped portion of something. I.e., the kind of triangle-shaped portions that you cut from pizza or round cheeses.

As a rule of thumb, you can't go wrong using "pedazo" or "trozo". "Pedazo" is more formal, "trozo" is more common. And if you are bold enough, "cacho" is another synonym; a bit rude, but fun in the right moment. Definitely recommended to impress your acquaintances.

Comment: "pedazo" formal? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

In Argentina the most natural traslation is: "Comí dos porciones de torta.”

The main translation of "slice" is "rebanada" or "rodaja", but that only applies for transversal cuts (bread). And when it's very thin (ham, bologna) we say "feta".